# Including Primary and foreign keys in DTD

Tags: xml, foreign-keys, primary-key, dtd

Im working on a task using XML and DTD (which I'm new to) and have been provided the image below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rITGv.png)

The question I'm working on reads:
*"Design a proper DTD called company.dtd for the information given by the above
relational database schema. The valid XML documents under this DTD must have
a tree structure with as much nesting as possible. The DTD must also capture all
the primary key and foreign key constraints"*

I have written the code below so far but im unsure about how to represent foreign and primary keys.
Does ID and IDREF answer the question in terms of keys?

```
<!DOCTYPE Company
[

    <!ELEMENT Company (Division+, Project+, Employee+, Assign+)>

    <!ELEMENT Division (DID, DNAME, LOCATION)>
        <!ELEMENT DID (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT DNAME (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT LOCATION (#PCDATA)>
        <!ATTLIST Division DID ID #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT Project (PID, PNAME, BUDGET, DID)>
        <!ELEMENT PID (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT PNAME (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT BUDGET (#PCDATA)>
        <!ATTLIST Project PID ID #REQUIRED>
        <!ATTLIST Project DID IDREF #REQUIRED>


    <!ELEMENT Employee (EID+, ENAME, OFFICE, BIRTHDATE, SALARY, DID+)>
        <!ELEMENT EID (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT ENAME (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT OFFICE (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT BIRTHDATE (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT SALARY (#PCDATA)>
        <!ATTLIST Employee EID ID #REQUIRED>
        <!ATTLIST Employee DID IDREF #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT Assign (PID+, EID+, HOURS)>
        <!ELEMENT HOURS (#PCDATA)>
        <!ATTLIST Assign PID IDREF #REQUIRED>
        <!ATTLIST Assign EID IDREF #REQUIRED>
]
```

> 